# quadrotor navigation by goal?

Tags: quadcopter, slam, navigation, uav, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to simulate a quadrotor on ros using gazebo and hector_quadrotor package, what I want to realize is navigation by goal using already realized ros component. For now I'm able to create a map of the simulated environment using rgbdslam and octomap_server, what i want to do now is use this rappresentation of the world to avoid collision and set a goal state for the simulated uav.

Is it possible?
What packages should I look for?
Are there some tutorials or readings on this argument and how to realize this in Ros?

What I have thinked so far is to use the armNavigation or moveit! package to plan a trajectory for the UAV, but I don't know if this is possible because they were designed for arm's moving.
The navigation stack only offer 2D support so doesn't work for a flying object.

For now I don't consider kinematic constraint, what I want to achieve it's pure geometric planning.

Thank you for your time!
Any advice it's welcome!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72238/quadrotor-navigation-by-goal?/) by [Alex2309](https://answers.ros.org/users/4474/alex2309/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2013-08-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2013-08-12**:
do you need to navigate in height ? i have used the navigation stack to send my UAV to a goal, but it just woks for paths in 2D, so it cannot plan a path over a table, but can plan it beside a table. I have just finished that in a simulation, dont know when i bring it on the real UAV.

**Comment by [Alex2309](https://answers.ros.org/users/4474/alex2309/) on 2013-08-12**:
if it's possible i would prefer to navigate also in height, but thanks for the advice anyway!

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2014-01-13**:
Hi, @Alex2309, could you tell me how to create a map of the environment using rgbdslam and octomap_server and kinect?

**Comment by [LisCampo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21955/liscampo/) on 2015-03-26**:
Hi @pkohout
Can you describe me how you plan plan beside a table with UAV?

**Comment by [automate](https://answers.ros.org/users/25620/automate/) on 2016-01-15**:
Hey @pkohout How did u generate odometry data which is required by navigation stack for navigating in 2d? Using MAVROS?    Did u use raw IMU data or GPS data or anything else? Is yes then can u describe how did u do it?

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2016-06-09**:
@pkohout I am trying to use the navigation stack with UAV.. Is there any tutorial or a github package that include this specification ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

MoveIt is not specific to arm planning. As I understand what you are trying to do, all you will need to do is specify that your robot is free flying (aka, a 'floating' joint connection between the world and the robot). This you can do when creating the moveit configuration package for your robot. At that point you should be able to do motion planning with collision avoidance. octomap is used internally, but octomap_server is not (the pipeline for processing sensor data in moveit is significantly more efficient).

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alex2309](https://answers.ros.org/users/4474/alex2309/) on 2013-08-12**:
thank you, I'm going to try this!
I'm using octomap_server mainly to obtain a stable 3d map of the environment, for collision avoidance i will use the octomap integrated in moveit!

EDIT: it works! thank you so much!!

**Comment by [Anurag](https://answers.ros.org/users/28030/anurag/) on 2017-07-15**:
Can you give link to a detailed description of how you build the whole system/simulation? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@ZiyangLI If you only want map reconstruction using kinect rgbdslam alone does that, you can add an octomap_server connecting the output topic of rgbdslma to the input of octomap_server if you want a queryable map. But if you have in mind of doing some planning with the map switch to MoveIT, it's a complete framework for path planning that already implement map reconstruction with kinect. For example check out my work:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlBQLbmc03g
Code available in the description

---

Originally posted by [Alex2309](https://answers.ros.org/users/4474/alex2309/) with karma: 163 on 2014-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2014-01-13**:
Thank you very much for your reply! I have sent you a message to ask in detail via Youtube.